# find larger files under /tmp (owned by oracle user, size larger than 1 MiB) and truncate them

Tags: scripting, find

My requirement is to find files under `/tmp` owned by the `oracle` user, with size larger than 1 MiB then truncate those files (empty them). Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Please [edit] your question to include what you have tried, and explain where you got stuck. Include error messages (if any)

Comment: By *nullify*, do you mean reduce their size to 0 or delete them (unlink them from the directory they're found in)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4):

To bring their file size down to 0:

```
find /tmp/ -size +1048576c -user oracle -type f -exec truncate -s0 {} +
```

If your system doesn't have a `truncate` command:

```
find /tmp/ -size +1048576c -user oracle -type f -exec sh -c '
  ret=0
  for file do
    true > "$file" || ret=$?
  done
  exit "$ret"' sh {} +
```

Note however that both are unsafe as they have a race condition. A malicious user could replace a file or directory with a symbolic link to somewhere outside of `/tmp`¹ between the time `find` finds the files and `truncate` is invoked to truncate them, allowing them to make you truncate any file on the filesystem.

If your `find` supports `-execdir` and `zsh` is available on the system, you could avoid it by doing:

```
find /tmp/ -size +1048576c -user oracle -type f -execdir zsh -c '
  zmodload zsh/system
  ret=0
  for file do
    sysopen -o nofollow,truncate -wu3 -- $file || ret=$?
  done
  exit $ret' zsh {} +
```

Or with GNU `find` and GNU `dd`:

```
find /tmp/ -size +1048576c -user oracle -type f -execdir \
  dd 'of={}' conv=nocreat oflag=nofollow status=none ';' < /dev/null
```

To delete the files instead of shrinking them, you can do:

```
find /tmp/ -size +1048576c -user oracle -type f -delete
```

Which at least with GNU `find` is race-free. Or:

```
find /tmp/ -size +1048576c -user oracle -type f -execdir rm -f {} +
```

Other notes:

- you do need the trailing `/` after `/tmp` if `/tmp` itself is a symbolic link. `find /tmp`, in that case, would only consider the `/tmp` symlink itself.
- `-type f` is to restrict to *regular* files (excluding all other types of files including symlinks, directories, fifos, devices).

---

<sup>¹ though for a malicious actor to be able to do that for files owned by `oracle`, you'd need a system that allows making hard links to files you don't own (like after `sysctl -w fs.protected_hardlinks=0` on Linux), or the permissions of directories holding those oracle-owned files to be too permissive in the first place, or the `oracle` uid itself to be compromised.</sup>

Comment: If the file is still open for writing by an oracle process, the file_offset in the process may be such that the process is still writing to the original end of file. You'll wind up with the original size of the file being sparse and new data appended after that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`find /tmp -user oracle -size +1M  -exec rm -rf {} \;` will find files owned by user oracle that are greater than 1 MB and delete them.

Comment: Beware that with that `-r` option, if any of those large files are of type *directory*, then the directories **and their contents** will be deleted (including files of any type in there even those not owned by `oracle` or smaller that `1MiB`.

Comment: I don't want to delete files. I want to make their size to 0

Comment: @umasam please put that important piece of information [into your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/671816/edit). If you don't tell us we won't know